# XCode 5 - UIAWindow returning not visible

Tags: xcode, xcode5, ios-ui-automation

I'm making the move to XCode 5.0.2. I'm trying to get the automation working. I'm looking for help understanding why the automation system no longer recognizes my extra window as visible.

I have three UIAWindow objects under my UIAApplication. The top window is the application, the next is the status bar, and the third is a debug tool. My debug tool window is no longer being recognized as visible by the automation system. It can be seen on the device. It can be interacted with on the device. It can be seen under the application's element tree. It shows as Valid and Enabled. However, all .isVisible() calls against elements in the window return false. The automation system just doesn't want to interact with the elements.

I have setWindowLevel set to UIWindowLevelAlert. I have setHidden to NO. All this worked just fine in XCode 4. I noticed that when I used makeKeyAndVisible on my debug window, the automation system (magically) started working with it. As soon as I'd run [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] self] window] makeKeyAndVisible], it would stop being considered visible. I can't let the debug window hold the keyboard focus, that's a bad bandaid. Maybe there's some new setting I'm missing?

Any ideas or questions you have, please don't hesitate to ask.